# Python clickhouse-driver: ValueError: Parameters are expected in dict form

Tags: python, clickhouse

I have some ETL that saves data to clickhouse with clickhouse-driver.

Save function looks exactly like this:

```
def insert_data(data: Iterable[Dict], table: str, client: Client = None):
    columns = get_table_cols(table)
    client = client or get_ch_client(0)
    query = f"insert into {table} ({', '.join(columns)}) values"
    data = map(lambda row: {key: row[key] for key in columns}, data)
    client.execute(query, data)
```

Function that calls `insert_data` looks like this:

```
def save_data(data: DataFrame, client: Client):

    mapper = get_mapper(my_table_map)
    data = map(lambda x: {col_new: getattr(x, col_old)
                          for col_old, col_new in map_dataframe_to_ch.items()},
               data.collect())
    data = map(mapper, data)
    insert_data(data, 'my_table_name', client)
```

`get_mapper` returns a map function that looks like this:

```
def map_row(row: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    nonlocal map_
    return {key: map_[key](val) for key, val in row.items()}
```

So basically in the end i have some nested generators that produce dictionaries. And to confirm this, if i put `print(next(data))` just before `client.execute` i get exactly the dict that i expect. Here is an example with sensitive info hidden:

```
{'account_currency': '***', 
 'instrument': '***',
 'operation': 'open',
 'event_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 7, 19, 11, 49),
 'country': 'CN',
 'region': 'Asia and Pacific',
 'registration_source': '***',
 'account_type': '***',
 'platform': '***',
 'server_key': '***'}
```

Table schema is as follows:

```
"account_currency": "String",
"instrument": "String",
"operation": "String",
"event_time": "DateTime",
"country": "String",
"region": "String",
"registration_source": "String",
"account_type": "String",
"platform": "String",
"server_key": "String"
```

But for whatever reason is i get this error:

```
  File "src/etl/usd_volume/prepare_users.py", line 356, in <module>
    main()
  File "src/etl/usd_volume/prepare_users.py", line 348, in main
    save_data(data, client)
  File "src/etl/usd_volume/prepare_users.py", line 302, in save_data
    insert_data(data, 'report_traded_volume_usd', client)
  File "/root/data/src/common/clickhouse_helper.py", line 14, in insert_data
    client.execute(query, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 224, in execute
    columnar=columnar
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 341, in process_ordinary_query
    query = self.substitute_params(query, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 422, in substitute_params
    raise ValueError('Parameters are expected in dict form')
```

According to docs:

> :param params: substitution parameters for SELECT queries and data for
> INSERT queries. Data for INSERT can be `list`, `tuple`
> or :data:`~types.GeneratorType`.
> Defaults to `None` (no parameters  or data).

So clearly my data fits these requirements.

However in the source code there is only this check:

```
def substitute_params(self, query, params):
    if not isinstance(params, dict):
        raise ValueError('Parameters are expected in dict form')

    escaped = escape_params(params)
    return query % escaped
```

I didn't really find where they check for it to be a generator.
Clickhouse-driver version is 0.1.4

Any help on this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you provide the schema of CH table? what version of *clickhouse_driver* used?

Comment: in insert_data `data` is a Generator? try maybe to make `data` list? do `client.execute(query, list(data))`.

Comment: Yes, it is a generator. I'm not making it a list as its length is going to be millions of dicts, it has to stay a generator. Also, i don't think this is the problem as according to source code `data` should basically be an iterable, no matter what kind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, further research on source code revealed the root cause.

The function that throws error `substitute_params` is called within the `process_ordinary_query` method of `Client` class. This method is basically called for any query other than INSERT.

The sign of query being either INSERT or any other is checked by this part of `execute` method:

```
is_insert = isinstance(params, (list, tuple, types.GeneratorType))

if is_insert:
    rv = self.process_insert_query(
        query, params, external_tables=external_tables,
        query_id=query_id, types_check=types_check,
        columnar=columnar
    )
else:
    rv = self.process_ordinary_query(
        query, params=params, with_column_types=with_column_types,
        external_tables=external_tables,
        query_id=query_id, types_check=types_check,
        columnar=columnar
    )
```

The crux is `isinstance(params, (list, tuple, types.GeneratorType))`

`types.GeneratorType` is defined as follows:

```
def _g():
    yield 1
GeneratorType = type(_g())
```

Which leads to this:

```
>>>GeneratorType
<class 'generator'>
```

Obviously, for my data which is `map`:

```
>>>type(map(...))
<class 'map'>
>>>isinstance(map(...), GeneratorType)
False
```

So the simplest solution to avoid this problem is to simply convert `data` into generator with generator comprehension. And that solves problem completely.

```
>>>data = (i for i in data)
>>>isinstance(data, GeneratorType)
True
```

Or if you are going to execute INSERT queries exclusively, you could just call `process_insert_query` directly, that will lift the need to convert data to generator.

I think this is a bit of an ambiguous type checking by clickhouse-driver, but this is what we have.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! I just faced a similar issue and that was the solution! :)